# If $A\subset B$ are integral domains with the same field of fractions and $B$ is faithfully flat over $A$, then $A=B$.

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, flatness

I found this exercise in Matsumura, *Commutative Ring Theory*, (Exercise 7.2).

> If $A\subset B$ are integral domains with the same field of fractions and $B$ is faithfully flat over $A$, then $A=B$.

Can anyone give me a proof for this statement or tell me where to find it?

Comment: May be you can use that: Let $A$ be an integral domain and $K$ be its field of fractions. Also let $B$ be a finitely generated $A$-submodule of $K$. Then $B$ is flat iff $B$ is locally free of rank $1$.